# Avoid line between tiled SVG shapes

Tags: layout, svg, rendering

I am using multiple differently colored rectangles to build a SVG data visualization.  This works great but sometimes background color bleeds through between the rectangles.  I am browsing with Chrome but other browsers seem similarly affected.

http://jsfiddle.net/dVEPk/

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <rect x="10.5" y="10" height="100" width="100"
          style="stroke:none; fill: #00cc00"/>
  <rect x="110.5" y="10" height="100" width="100"
          style="stroke:none; fill: #00cc00"/>
</svg>
```

In Chrome, if the x offset is an integer, the line is not visible.

I'm sure I can avoid lines by making rectangles a little larger than the space they have to occupy.  But this seems like a hack: is there an SVG idiom or best practice to achieve perfectly tiled shapes without "grout"?

I'm also concerned by rendering performance because my visualizations can be very large (say 100MB XML .svg).  I'd like to be able to give the renderer hints like "none of the shapes in this `<g>` are overlapping"?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is antialiasing at work between the shape and the background. If you want to turn it off set shape-rendering="crispEdges" on the shapes. You can either set that on the rect elements or on the `<svg>` in which case the rect elements will inherit it.

You may be able to adjust the line's positions by adding 0.5 to the co-ordinates. See the [cairo FAQ](http://cairographics.org/FAQ/#sharp_lines) for more details on this.

Comment: Wow, that works great... I guess a downside is that when shapes themselves are around pixel-size or smaller their colors will be aliased.

Comment: crispEdges disables antialiasing. If you draw diagonal lines you'll see that they seem rougher than antialiased lines.

Comment: Isn't there a solution that doesn't break the anti-aliasing necessary for rounded lines? this solution solves one problem while creating another...

Comment: @matt Not with SVG 1.1 and the current browser renderers, I'm afraid. The only thing you can do is work around the problem by adding borders or otherwise having shapes overlap. This doesn't work if the shapes are non opaque. You might try putting in an aliased shape that fills exactly fills in the gap, but my experiences is that the gap tends to change sizes depending on magnification. And, with straight lines, you can try just using exact pixel boundaries, but, again, that breaks on scaling.

Comment: @trlkly Works for me in Chrome though...?

Comment: @Domi what works for you? All I said is that there is no option that both disables antialiasing between shapes but keeps it on the background. If you've found a way to do that, please share.

Comment: @trlkly Oh nevermind! I just re-read, and realized: I am using `crispEdges` which works fine on my "rects-only" image, but since it turns off anti-aliasing, it won't work on most types of images! I don't understand though: Which property of the anti-aliasing algorithm leaves blanks between shapes, if the are supposed to touch each other? If anything, the pixels at the border should be a blur of the touching shapes, or am I mistaken?

Comment: Proably best if you ask a new question, include your example code and state clearly what its doing and what you want it to do.

Comment: I've been having issues with small gaps between SVG elements and this immediately solved it. Thanks!

Comment: This only works for certain simple (rectilinear? polygonal?) shapes. Concentric circles for instance will still show the gap even with antialiasing turned off.