# Avoid line between tiled SVG rects that are NOT pixel aligned

Tags: svg, rendering

I have several nearby `rect`s like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049336/avoid-line-between-tiled-svg-shapes), but not aligned to pixels. I can not change the element positions. [For instance](http://tinkerbin.com/73t2Oz33):

```
<svg width="326.01071" height="255.5332" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   viewBox="18 18 41 41"
>
    <rect x="21" y="21" width="51" height="3" fill="black" class="crisp" />
    <rect x="21" y="24" width="30" height="3" fill="black" class="crisp" />
    <rect x="21" y="41" width="51" height="3" fill="black" />
    <rect x="21" y="44" width="30" height="3" fill="black" />
</svg>​
```

I'm getting a thin line between the rects. `shape-rendering="crispEdges"` doesn't help.

Adding a bit of overlap helps a bit, but causes visible spikes on a vertical joints where two antialiased edges join, as both the overlapping rects participate in color blending.

Is there anything I can do?

*Well, the rects are of the same color, so I can introduce some intelligent algorithm to join the adjacent rects into one shape. That's one clean, but hard way.*

Comment: Does it help to add a thin stroked outline of the same color?

Comment: My bad, shape-rendering is indeed inherited from a root svg element. A working jsfiddle would help as your example code has no problems rendering sharp with `crispEdges` see http://tinkerbin.com/wAeATCVs

Comment: I updated my sample with what was causing the line, a `viewBox`. And your tinkerbin contained the answer: the `g` tag eliminated the line! (well, except for in IE9) Will you please repost this as an answer?

Comment: Glad it helped. I think the correct etiquette in this case would be to answer your own question as I'm still not sure what you did to correct it!

Comment: I'd prefer if you answer - it's your knowledge that I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'll answer in the end.

Adding `g` tag around `rect`-s eliminated the line — with the exception of Internet Explorer.

Comment: the tinkerbin is gone by now, but adding a plain g tag around the rectangles does not work in latest-version Chrome in my case. Is there a reason a g tag should make a difference?

Comment: No idea, sorry. I was completely in the dark here.