# Why is there whitespace / "overlap" between rect elements where there shouldn't be?

Tags: javascript, svg, colors, d3.js, antialiasing

I'm using d3.js to generate some rects which are directly above one another, in this fashion:

```
var greenRed = d3.select(".green-red").append("svg")
    .attr("height", 120);
greenRed.append("rect")
    .attr("fill", "green")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("height", 50)
    .attr("width", 300);
greenRed.append("rect")
    .attr("fill", "red")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 50)
    .attr("height", 50)
    .attr("width", 300);
```

I've noticed that depending on which colours are stacked on top of one another, there is either a very thin whitespace present between the rectangles, or a sort of "overlap" of the two colours.

You can see what I mean in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ysim/PrC7X/

You can see that for `.green-green` and `.green-grey` there's no issue (to the naked eye, anyway); but for `.green-blue` and `.red-blue`, there is an overlap, and for `.green-red`, there is an extra whitespace.

I've tried adding `.attr("stroke-rendering", "crispEdges")` (suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049336/avoid-line-between-tiled-svg-shapes)) and `.attr("stroke", "none")` to the `rect` elements, as well as wrapping both the `rect` elements in a `g` element within the `svg` and adding `.attr("stroke-rendering", "crispEdges")` to *that* (suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13457803/avoid-line-between-tiled-svg-rects-that-are-not-pixel-aligned)), but neither of those solutions work.

What's causing this extra whitespace/overlap, and how do I go about fixing it so that the colours are neatly aligned, like in the first two cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's antialiasing. Add  style="shape-rendering: crispEdges" to the `<div>` elements and it will go away. You could add it to the shapes themselves instead if you want either as an attribute or a style.

The other thing to do is to [add 0.5 to the y co-ordinates of your shapes](http://jsfiddle.net/longsonr/gmxZq/) There's more information about why that works [here](http://cairographics.org/FAQ/#sharp_lines)

Comment: You mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/ysim/K6pfD/ 

It didn't seem to do anything. Or did you mean in conjunction with something that was mentioned above?

Comment: Sure, that fixes it for me on Firefox (although you've missed the first two).

Comment: Strange. In Chrome, for `.green-green`, there is no whitespace, even without `style=shape-rendering:crispEdges`, but in Firefox there is a whitespace that *is* fixed by `crispEdges`. I'm still seeing the issue for `.green-blue` onwards in both browsers though.

Comment: I've updated my post. Seems even better in Firefox now. You'll have to check Chrome yourself

Answer (score 2):

try setting the stroke-width property to 0