# SVG rect spacing

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a bunch of SVG rects side by side. Somehow there is a small margin between them (the thin black line), why is this? How can I remove it? See attached pictures:

[image: Rect code]
[image: SVG rects]

Code:

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%"><rect height="100%" width="25%" x="0%" fill="rgb(0,0,255)"></rect><rect height="100%" width="25%" x="25%" fill="rgb(0,0,220)"></rect><rect height="100%" width="25%" x="50%" fill="rgb(0,0,200)"></rect><rect height="100%" width="25%" x="75%" fill="rgb(0,0,150)"></rect></svg>
```

Comment: Would you mind to share code?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/13049336/2126792